# Can not see approve button on Expense Report

Tags: netsuite

We are facing a weird issue on expense report.

As a supervisor, I can see approve button for an expense report of my employee. But as an Accounting, i cant see any approve button after that has been approved by his supervisor.

Has anyone faced this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Approve button for Accounting on Expense Reports.  They have to edit the expense report, check the Accounting Approval box and save it.  NetSuite doesn't really know who is in Accounting and who isn't so it can't reliably display a button there.  The organization of Accounting is different for different companies.

You can create a workflow that puts an approve button on the expense report and check that box when they click the button.

Comment: thank you Mike .. however, when i go to edit as an AP, cant even see the Accounting Approval box ( even if thats checked as visible in the form setup), wondering why so ..

Comment: You need to make sure they're using the Accounting Center, they have Edit or Full for Transactions -> Expense Reports, and that their role does not have the 'Restrict Time and Expenses' box checked.

Comment: all set like what you said, still no luck :(